# Looking for best approach to sending the same data to multiple destinations using sockets

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, queue

Looking for the best approach to sending the same message to multiple destinations using TCP/IP sockets.  I'm working with an existing VS 2010 C++ application on Windows.   Hoping to use a standard library/design pattern approach that has many of the complexities already worked out if possible.

Here's one approach I'm thinking about..   One main thread retrieves messages from a database and adds them to some sort of thread safe queue.   The application also has one thread for each client socket connection to some destination server.   Each one of these threads would read from the thread safe queue, and send the message over a tcp/ip socket.
There may be better/simpler/more robust approaches than this one though..

The issues I have to be concerned about mostly are latency.  The destinations could be anywhere, and there may be significant latency between one socket connection and another.
The messages must go in an exact FIFO order to all the destinations.

Also one destination will be considered the primary destination..  all messages must get to this destination, no exceptions.   For the other destinations, i.e. non-primary, the messages are just copies and it's not absolutely critical if the non-primary destinations do not receive a few messages.   At any point, one of the non-primary destinations could become the primary destination.   If one of the destinations falls too far behind, then that thread would need to catch up to the primary destination, but skipping some messages.

Looking for any suggestions.   Preliminary research so far, my situation appears to be something akin to a single producer and multiple consumers pattern, or possibly master-worker pattern in Java.

I need to implement this in C++ on Windows, and the application must use tcp/ip sockets using an existing defined protocol.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I dunno what "existing defined protol" means, but take a look at [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org)

Comment: TCP already does a lot of this: guaranteed FIFO ordering, for a start, and as long as the connection to the primary destination (or indeed any destination) stays up, the peer at that destination will receive all data sent. I'm not clear why latency is such a concern from your description: it doesn't affect ordering for example.

Comment: "Existing defined protocol" for me simply means that the application is communicating with servers where the interface/protocol has already been defined.  Meaning TCP/IP is a requirement.

Comment: Yes I understand about TCP guaranteed FIFO ordering, and TCP/IP is a requirement for this application.   Essentially the architecture is one client sending the exact same message to multiple servers.  ZeroMQ refers to this I believe as Fan Out.    The one client will need to send the same message to approximately 12 servers.   The client will be sending about 10 kilobits of messages per second to all 12 servers.

Comment: The reason why I mention latency as a concern is because the client will be sending every second 24 hours a day/7 days a week, 10 kilobits worth of messages every second to all 12 servers.  If one of the servers falls behind, it would never catch up, and would always be behind.  Its only critical that the one primary server gets all messages, for the other 11 servers its ok to drop some messages in order for the non-primary servers to catch up to the primary server.   Hopefully I've explained this better.

Comment: One other thing I should mention to be clear, the 12 servers that the one client will be sending messages will be using plain old standard tcp/ip sockets that is another hard requirement.   I only have control over what libraries or software for the client, and no control over whatsoever of the servers which have already been coded using plain tcp/ip sockets.   From what I'm reading I can't have a ZeroMQ client talking to a server that's just using plain tcp/ip sockets?

Answer (score 0):

You need exactly two threads, one that saturates the IO channel to the database and another that saturates the IO channel to the network leading to the 12 servers. Unless you have multiple network interfaces (which you should think about!) you don't send things faster by using multiple threads. Also, since you don't have multiple threads taking care of the network, you don't have to sync them.

What you definitely need to know about is select(). In the case of WinSock, also take a look at WSAEventSelect/WaitForMultipleObjects. Basically, you take a message from the queue and then send it to all clients when they're ready. select() tells you when one of a set of sockets is ready to accept data, so you don't waste time waiting or block trying to send data. What you need to come up with is a schema to reconnect after broken connections, when to drop messages to lagging clients etc. Also, in case the throughput to the different targets varies a lot, you need to think about handling multiple messages in parallel. If they are small (less than a network packet's payload) it makes sense combining them anyway to avoid overhead.

I hope this short overview helps getting you started, otherwise I can elaborate on the details.